# Magento Category Custom Design Page Layout not changing

Tags: magento, enterprise

I have turned off caching, but not matter what I do when I edit Admin -> Catalog -> Categories. Then click on the Custom Design and edit Page Layout, and layout from 1 - 3 columns.

[image]

None of the changes show up. I've tried this for the Default Site and specific site per category with no updates reflecting the front-end. I can edit the Custom Layout Update area and use something like:

```
   <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
```

Or I can edit the local.xml file and force all categories to be a specific layout:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>

<catalog_category_layered>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_layered>
```

However I need the Page Layout options to work. Maybe this has something to do with the layout in local.xml that add / removed things from the left and right side? As a note in the CMS Pages area, I can successfully change the Page Layout.

Comment: I was unable to replicate your issue. Use magento's default theme and try 3column custom layout then turn on template hints system->configuration->developer->template/block hints on and tell me which template outputs on that categories page as the outermost container.

Comment: The outer most container is always template/page/1column.phtml even if I change it to 3 column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the issue. I relied on another theme which forced the catalog_category_default to always render 2 columns. This was because update handle sets the applied variable to 1 which ignores admin page layout changes.

Here is what it is doing:

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <update handle="page_two_columns_left"/>
    ...
</catalog_category_default>
```

So the only way I could override it was from my own XML update, but it still did not let me update the page layout from the admin.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

So the fix was to set the applied variable to 0.

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>0</applied></action>
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

This lets me use the **Category Layout** from the **Custom Design** tab in the **Category Admin**

I found this out by locating the handle and reviewing what variables it set. So here was the definition of page_two_columns_left:

```
<page_two_columns_left translate="label">
    <label>All Two-Column Layout Pages (Left Column)</label>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
        <!-- Mark root page block that template is applied -->
        <action method="setIsHandle"><applied>1</applied></action>
        <action method="setLayoutCode"><name>two_columns_left</name></action>
    </reference>
</page_two_columns_left>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the reference code to change the layout, do so in admin control panel:

> Go to categories / custom design

Find the page layout selection and change to 2 columns with either left or right bar.

Comment: You really should use correct syntax and capitalization on your answer, so it is easier to read and will have a better chance of being accepted.

Comment: I did do that and that not working. I can change it to any column layout and it does not work. I've updated the question to show where I am going and what I am editing.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution:

use the layout update:

```
 <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

In this way the page layout is changed regardless of the `is_handle` value